# GnatBench runtime

Tags: eclipse, runtime, ada, gnat

I am trying to make Eclipse compile Ada projects. I installed CDT and GNATBench 2014 (seems to be the latest) under Eclipse Neon 2 and the native compiler seems to be working fine. However, when I try to cross compile another project which uses a customized run-time system with statement `for Runtime ("Ada") use project;` in the gpr file, Eclipse complains that `undefined attribute "runtime"`. The GPS tool compiles this project fine.

What is missing from the Eclipse installation? I use latest Ubutu with the necessary libs installed.

**EDIT:** To clarify, I am using gprbuild. The gpr file looks like this:

```
project TEST is

  for Target use "leon-elf";
  for Languages use ("Ada", "Asm_Cpp");
  for Object_Dir use "./obj";
  for Main use ("main.adb");
  for Source_Dirs use (".");
  for Runtime ("ada") use project'Project_Dir & "../ada-rts-grm";
  for Exec_Dir use "./obj";

  package Linker is
     for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-g", "-gdwarf-3", "-gstrict-dwarf", "-Wl,-Map,roic.map");
     for Linker_Options use ();
  end Linker;

  package Ide is
     for Gnat use "leon-elf-gnat";
     for Gnatlist use "leon-elf-gnatls";
     for Debugger_Command use "leon-elf-gdb";
  end Ide;

  package Compiler is
     for Switches ("ada") use ("-gnatwa.V.i.s", "-gdwarf-3", "-O3", "-gnatn", "-funroll-loops", "-gnatp");
  end Compiler;

  package Binder is
  end Binder;

  package Builder is
     for Executable ("main.adb") use "main.elf";
  end Builder;

end TEST;
```

Comment: which tool is used for building? gnatmake or gprbuild ? could you post you .gpr file?

Comment: @flotto, Hi, please see the edit in the question.

Comment: eclipse and GPS should call gprbuild, can you verify they are using the same command ? btw. having a gpr file is not a gurarantee using gprbuild, bcause gnatmake will work with gpr files either. Have you tried using gprbuild from cmd ?

Comment: @flotto, I am sure that gprbuild is used, because if I run compilation with gprbuild in a terminal window, then the project compiles fine. Eclipse also shows that it tries to invoke gprbuild for the project compilation when no `Runtime` attribute is mentioned. It seems that the problem is only related to the Eclipse setup.

Comment: Hmm, do you have multiple versions of gnat installed? can you check the eclipse build command (maybe use an absolut path to gprbuild) ?

Comment: I have two gnat compilers installed: leon-elf and linux i386 native. The problem is that even when I try to import the project with runtime system set as in question, I get an error `8:8:undefined attribute "runtime"`. So, I think that the problem is not really in the compiler; rather, in the gnat-bench extension for Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this eclipse plug-in with the Adacore GNAT ARM compiler, that has several runtimes.
Inside Eclipse with the GNATbench plug-in it is more secure to define all the attributes before using it, putting its definition into the project.gpr:

```
type Runtime_Type is
   ("ada-rts-grm", "any-other-runtime");
Runtime: Runtime_Type := external ("RUNTIME", "ada-rts-grm");
```

This instructs gnatmake and gprbuild to use the variable RUNTIME defined externally and, if it is not defined, it will use de default "ada-rts-grm".
If you want to define RUNTIME externally, do it before calling eclipse in the command prompt:

```
RUNTIME="any-runtime"; export RUNTIME
<eclipse_path>eclipse
```

The problem is that there is no path defined inside Eclipse to find RTS. So you need to put inside the package Builder:

```
package Builder is
   for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-g", "--RTS=" & external ("RUNTIME_PATH", "") & "ada-rts-grm");
end Builder
```

and you define

```
RUNTIME_PATH="runtime_path/"; export RUNTIME_PATH
<eclipse_path>eclipse
```

or

```
package Builder is
   for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-g", "--RTS=" & project'Project_Dir & "../ada-rts-grm");
end Builder
```

You may confirm that the variables are defined in your program going to:
Window -> Show View -> Scenario Variables (or Other... -> Scenario Variable, if it is not there).

Now the problem is that the ARM GNAT compiler from Adacore doesn't have the file "arm-eabi-gnatmake", so the plug-in will not find a compiler, even gprbuild doesn't work. The workaround is to get a "gnatmake" from another distribution that has been compiled for ARM architecture. MuntsOs (http://repo.muntsos.com) has a compiler tool for Linux ARM that may be used. Rename the file "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gnatmake" to "arm-eabi-ganatmake" and put it inside the "bin" directory from Adacore GNAT ARM compiler path.

And that's all. Now you may compile your ARM projects with RTS inside Eclipse with gnatmake or gprbuild.